# why the printf function showing desired output in the following code?

Tags: c++, printf, calling-convention

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=1;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",a,++a,a++);
    return 0;
}
```

Why the output of the code is `3 3 1`. someone explain me how this kind of output happen?

Comment: @BattleTested - `cstdio` looks like a C++ header to me.

Comment: @play store - Did you not get a warning like this : **warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]** ?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes your right....

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your compiler reads the parameters from right to left

```
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",a,++a,a++); // a = 1
```

a++ returns a and increments it by 1

```
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",a,++a, 1); // a = 2
```

++a increments a by 1 and returns the result

```
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",a, 3, 1); // a = 3
```

a is just a

```
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", 3, 3, 1); // a = 3
```

But AFAIK this is kinda UB because the c++ standard doesnt rule in which order the parameters are read, so I wouldnt bet on it beeing the same on different compilers

Edit: With C++17 its no longer UB but unspecified. You should still avoid it

Comment: please see the comment from [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller) below my answer. It isn't always UB anymore. In C++17 it is unspecified.

Comment: Ive read it. But "unspecified" is just slightly better than UB. Compiler specific implementations should be avoided too

Comment: totally agreed, but your answer becomes better when it is included :)

Comment: your last 2 paragraphs could be reprhased a bit. When there is UB it does not just mean that you get them evaluated in unpredictable order, but UB is something the compiler may assume to never happen, hence before C++17 not only the outcome is undefined but the whole code could do anything, with C++17 you still dont know the order, but there is no UB, which is a fundamental difference

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behaviour as per the order of evaluation. [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) (see chapter Undefined behavior)

The output is:

> 3 3 1

because it evaluates as follows:

> a++
> use a(1) and a becomes 2
> ++a
> a becomes 3 and use a(3)
> use a(3)

Important is to know that `a++` is post-increment and `++a` is pre-increment.
Post-increment means: use the value and increase it after.
Pre-increment means: increment the value and use the incremented value.

## sidenote: C++17 changed this from undefined behaviour to unspecified but in previous versions it still is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You should read the (since C++17) section more closely. It's no longer UB, just unspecified.

Comment: the cppreference page is a bit vague on that . (I personally don't see a C++17 section) but indeed it isn't UB anymore. Do you have any updated documentation on the order of evaluation in c++17?

Comment: Easy to miss the mentions of C++17 on mobile. Anyway, the very reference you link to has plenty of examples that say "undefined behavior until C++17".

Comment: Stupid me, I was expecting a "since C++17" somewhere but of course the statement unspecified is all the documentation needed for that.